# Why Suggested Edits in the other user's answer is been rejected in my Own question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I need someone clarify me:

I [Asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944072/php-enconding-formatting-cedilla-in-portuguese-is-not-working) which was answered by user that helps me fix part of the problem.

I just added some information about one of my problem which user's answer couldn't find a solution for me. This information is relevant and important for other users that will possible face same issue as I did.

Its not fair allege that ***This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer*** since I just complement with his answer.

I need an position and suggestion on how to edit an answer without being rejected one more time. I cannot see why my edit will (sorry my language) screw up owner answer...

Comment: If you were seeking advice on how not to be rejected a 2nd time, why did you propose the same exact edit a 2nd time before getting feedback from this question

Comment: Because I didn't see how this change affects original content. It was a complement guys... Its an important information.

Comment: For reference, these were the two edits in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7309220 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7308935

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be editing another person's post to add your own original content.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of the answer, not to alter its content.

As the rejection reason states; you should either add the information as a comment, or as a new answer, not as an edit.

Comment: But did you see what I tried to "change"? I just add some information inside my context and content problem that I asked. I cannot see how my changes could affect original content. Its clearly a complement what owner's answer proposed.

Comment: @bcesars As I said, you were adding your own original *content* to the post.  You should not be editing posts to just add your own additional content.  Adding new content, even if you think it's complimentary, shouldn't be done in an edit.

Comment: @bcesars it is a change because you are adding content and new information that was not part of the original.  This is how the community decided the system should work with regards to editing.  If you have new information, leave it as a comment (and maybe the author of the answer will edit it in himself), or leave it as your own answer.

Comment: Now I comprehended what you are saying guys. I'll ask owner answer if its possible to add this information without create another answer.